How to authenticate a user in Symfony with SSO?
I have an issue. I need to authenticate a user from an SSO Response in my App.
I have a valid SSO response, I pass the onAuthenticationSuccess in my authenticator but in my controller when I try  to get my User it returns null and I can see in the toolbar that I'm not Authenticated.
Here is my security.yaml :
security:    
    providers:
        app_admin_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Admin
                property: username
    firewalls:
        saml_login:
            pattern: /general/saml/
            security: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_admin_provider
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\SamlAuthenticator

Here is my SamlAuthenticator :
class SamlAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {}

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        if ($request->request->get('SAMLResponse')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $dataSSO = $this->getSSOReponse($request);

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $dataSSO['email']);

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($dataSSO['email'], function($username) {
            $admin = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Admin::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);

            if (! $admin) {
                throw new UserNotFoundException();
            }

            return $admin;
        }));
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request,TokenInterface $token,string $firewallName): Response|null
    {
        return null;
    }
}

In my 'onAuthenticationSuccess' method i can see the user in the token.
But then in the Controller the user is not authenticated.
Can anyone help me on this ?
In the 'authenticate' method i tried different ways to create the Passport.
return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($dataSSO['email']);

I tried also to put logic in the 'onAuthenticationSuccess' method.
Nothing worked.

The code seems fine in terms of handling authentication.
Question: Could you confirm whether the correct firewall is being used for authentication validation? Do you have multiple firewalls configured?
Is the URL where you validate the authentication prefixed with /general/saml/, such as in: http://yourapplication.com/general/saml/welcome ?
If not, that might be the issue.
Some improvements: Consider changing the class extension from AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator to AbstractAuthenticator, as SSO is not a LoginForm. This might not be causing the issue here, but it's a good practice.
Additionally, it’s better not to return null. Since you're using the TargetPath trait, you can implement the following example code:
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('index_from_your_firewall_route'));
}

